# Writing class based javascript models to be used in script tag with rollup and babel toolset

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

I'm building a javascript module in es6 and want to transpile it so it can even be used with a script tag in the browser.

Let's say I have 2 classes in es6

```js
//test.js
class Test
{
constructor() { 
this.txt = "Hello world!" 
}
} 
//game.js
import Test from './test.js';
class Game 
{ 
constructor() 
{ 
this.test = new Test();  
}
sendHello() { 
console.log(this.test.txt) 
}
}
```

Then I create a main.js file as the entry point for rollup.

```
import Game from './game.js';
const game = new Game;
export default game;
```

Now I want to use this in older browser.
So I use babel and rollup to package this.

```html
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import {terser} from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: [{
      file: 'dist/exported.js',
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap:true
    },
    {
      file: 'dist/exported.min.js',
      format: 'umd',
      sourcemap:true,
      name: 'version',
      plugins: [terser()]
    }],
    plugins: [ 
        json(),
        resolve(),
        babel({ babelHelpers: 'bundled' })
    ]
  };
```

And the babel config

```html
{
    "presets": [
      "@babel/env"
    ]
}
```

And now I want to use this exported.min.js in a script tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tets</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script
  src="./jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./dist/exported.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
      game.sendHello();
  }); // end of document ready
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I get game is undefined.
window.game is also undefined.
How should I do this the right way?
If I have these basics I can start writing modules that can be used in older javascript and browsers. But also in newer projects.

kind regards.
Roel

Answer (score 0):

try output options iife and not cjs
and assign manual to window.

```
import Game from './game.js';
const game = new Game;
window.game = game;
export default game;
```

```
    output: [{
      file: 'dist/exported.js',
      format: 'iife',
      sourcemap:true
    }
```